# Two networks with the same ESSID, how do I blacklist one or force the other?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, essid

I'm here at Starbucks in Kingwood, Texas at the intersection of Kingwood Drive, and West Lake Houston. I'm in a shopping outlet. In the same shopping center just 150 feet away is an ATT Store.

The problem I'm encountering is both the Starbucks, and the ATT Store broadcast as ESSID `attwifi`. Unfortunately, they both have two different methods of web-authentication/guest login, and even more unfortunately is one of them is quite normally out of range; I can just barely get the signal. How do I black list an access point (the one from the ATT Store) from nm-applet? Or, how do a force an AP (the one here at Starbucks) in iwconfig that won't revert based on ESSID?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this from the GUI network manager applet by choosing `Edit connections...`, choosing the `Wireless` tab, selecting the appropriate connection by SSID, and then entering the MAC address of the desired access point in the `BSSID` box

[image: network-manager bssid]

You can obtain the MAC addresses from the command line using the `nmcli` tool e.g.

```
nmcli dev wifi list
```

or to see just the MAC of the currently active connection

```
nmcli dev wifi list | awk '$NF ~ /yes/ {print}'
```

It should be possible to do the same with `iwconfig` - although it generally requires elevated privileges e.g.

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 ap 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

If `nmcli` is not available on your system, you can use `iwlist` to obtain the MAC information (although the output format is not as convenient for parsing)

```
iwlist wlan0 scan[ning]
```

(where `wlan0` is the interface name) will show the current AP; or to see all detected APs

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan[ning]
```